# Why does this work priority = ''-1 in Mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

Can anyone tell me why this works in mysql?

```
update routing_policy set priority=''-1 where id = 1;
```

Comment: What does "this works" mean in this case? It depends on what you really want to happen to the `priority` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're subtracting 1 from the empty string, evaluated as 0 for this purpose, therefore the result is -1. Take a look at the manual page about [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) for more about this.

Answer (score 2):

Your value for `priority is invalid:`priority=''-1`. You're attempting to subtract a number from a string *or* your value is outside of the quotes (which shouldn't be an issue if you used an integer data type).